# NodeJS MySQL - How to know connection is release or not

Tags: mysql, node.js, database-connection

I am developing NodeJS + MySQL web API.

I am using [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) npm module.

I want know connection is release or not is there any function or variable.
Like

```
if(!connection.isRelease() OR !connection.isClose() OR !connection.end()) {
    connection.release();
}
```

Is there any specific function to know connection is release or not?

I am getting error like "connection already release"

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can check if the connection is in the pool to see if it was released.  The index in the free connections will be -1 if the connection is not released. Here is an example.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 10,
  host            : 'localhost',
  user            : 'root',
  password        : ''
});

pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    connection.query( 'SELECT something FROM sometable', function(err, rows) {

      console.log(pool._freeConnections.indexOf(connection)); // -1

      connection.release();

      console.log(pool._freeConnections.indexOf(connection)); // 0

   });
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Just in case you don't have access to the pool you can also do this:

```
connection._pool._freeConnections.indexOf(connection)
```

This will give you the same answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: If we are going to use 'private' variables anyway, then this answer seems much simpler than the accepted one.

Comment: Yes occam's razor prefers this one. (does the same thing, but simpler)