# code: "PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_FATAL_ERROR" in nodeJs MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I have this issue since I uploaded my code on hosting panel, my Database is different server and API is a different server
The error is `code: "PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_FATAL_ERROR", fatal: false}`

it is working for some time but after calling another API then an error is occurring.
Here is my code

`app.js`

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'xx.xx.xx.xx',
  user     : 'abc',
  password : '123',
  database : 'XYZ',
 });

connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
      return;
    }
   console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
  });
```

Here is the controller `user.js`

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
   var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host     : 'xx.xx.xx.xx',
      user     : 'abc',
      password : '123',
      database : 'XYZ',
     })

This is one code snippet of my API.

exports.getLandLord =(req, res, next)=>{
    var sql =`SELECT *FROM  registrations`;
       connection.query(sql, function(error, result, field){
        if(error){
            return res.status(201).json({message:error, status:402, success:false})
        }
        else
        if(result.length>0){
            res.status(200).json({message:"Land Loard List", status:200, success:true, 
          users:result,})
        }
        else
        res.status(200).json({message:"No Record Found ", status:402, success:false, users:result})
    })


}
```

I tried googling but I was not able to make it fix.

Please can anyone help me with this issue

Your response and help would be highly appreciated

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your server running? (e.g node start app.js)

Comment: Yes it is running in my case it sever.js

Comment: Even I testing it with using localhost but online database connection same error occurring after some time later

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node JS Mysql PROTOCOL ENQUEUE AFTER FATAL ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31549193/node-js-mysql-protocol-enqueue-after-fatal-error)

Comment: I visited it but unable to implement it

Comment: Have you tried restarting it? Or kill all the node processes then start it again

Comment: Yes, Still same error

Comment: Did you happen to find this link when googling for answer? > 
 https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/1166

Answer (score 2):

After struggling for a long time I work around this and got code to work 
refer [NodeJS MySQL - How to know connection is release or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34542902/nodejs-mysql-how-to-know-connection-is-release-or-not)